# An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 119, position 40

Tags: html, xml, pdf, xslt

Although I find similar questions as mine, the answers to those questions don't answer my question. I'm trying to convert XML and XSLT into HTML so it can get converted to a PDF.

I have an HTML page (249 lines) that gets converted to XSLT:

```
`string filePath = hostURL + "path/to/somefile.htm";`

`xslt = client.DownloadData(filePath);`
```

The corresponding XML gets generated with `XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();`

then XmlElement nodes are added and MemoryStream xmlStream is returned where xslt and xmlStream are passed to

```
`string html = Helper.GenerateHTML(xmlStream, xslt);`
```

In `Helper.GenerateHTML(this MemoryStream xmlStream, byte[] xsltByte)` this occurs:

```
`XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
 settings.XmlResolver = null;
 settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;`

`using (var xsltMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(xsltByte))
 using (var xmlReader        = XmlReader.Create(xsltMemoryStream, settings))
 using (var xmlMemoryStream  = new MemoryStream())`

`using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlMemoryStream, null))
{                
    var xct = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xct.Load(xmlReader);
    ...
}`
```

but I get the error at `xct.Load(xmlReader);` and the Create PDF button click that invoked this code does not result in a PDF being created nor displayed.

Neither the XSL nor XML have symbol-related ("&" vs. "&", etc.) issues. For what it's worth, there is another process that extracts XSLT from the database (instead of an HTML file), generates its corresponding XML with `XMLGenerator xgen = new XMLGenerator()` then calls `Helper.GenerateHTML(xmlStream, xslt)` but does not choke at the `xct.Load(xmlReader);` line of code and a resulting PDF is displayed.

Why does the parsing error occur?

Comment: So how exactly does line 119 of the XSLT look?

Comment: And why is `filePath` assigned some `somefile.htm` but then treated as XSLT with `xslt = client.DownloadData(filePath)`?

Comment: 119: `<td><label>Order Dates:</label></td>`

and I had been getting the error at line 137:


137:  `<td><xsl:value-of select="/FormData/Checklist/SomeDate" /></td>`

client is of type `WebClient client = new WebClient();` ... and the DownloadData() method takes a string.

Comment: Are you sure the content passed as `xsltByte` is XSLT code and not the HTML you also seem to want to process? Why do you need to use a byte array anyway and can't just pass the URL of the XSLT to the method and then to the `Load` method or at least an XmlReader with the right settings? But I doubt that causes the problem, just seems odd and kind of inadequate to deal with loading XML/XSLT with `DownloadData` while all XML APIs know how to deal with URLs directly.

Comment: Yes, when xslt is passed to the Helper.GenerateHTML(...) method, it's an xsltByte. client.DownloadData(...) returns byte[]. xslt is declared at the class level: `protected byte[] xslt`

It's the existing legacy code ... and I don't know much about handling XML/XSLT.

Comment: You so far have not explained why you seem to assign a path ending with `somefile.htm` (so probably an HTML document) to `filePath` but then treat it as your XSLT in `xslt = client.DownloadData(filePath)`. That part doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's the way the code is written. I appreciate you responding but do you know what the solutions is?

Comment: So far you have not presented any details like minimal but complete samples to allow anyone to reproduce and understand the problem. Solving the problem requires being able to understand and reproduce it.